# Adding a tag to an email file creates an error

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I created a script that receives last minute emails if they do not contain a "a" tag and sends the content of the message to a function I called "ssfunction" and then adds the "a" tag to it
And this is the script I made:

```
const threads = GmailApp.search('-{label:a}');
 for (const thread of threads) {
   const messages = thread.getMessages();
   const minuteAgo = new Date(Date.now() - 60000);
   if (thread.getLastMessageDate() > minuteAgo) {
     for (const message of messages) {
       if (message.getDate() > minuteAgo) {
       const result = ssfunction(message);
       didUpload = result || didUpload;
       }
     }
     thread.addLabel("a");
   } else {
     const result = ssfunction(messages[messages.length - 1]);
     didUpload = result || didUpload;
     thread.addeLabel("a");
   }
```

But I get such an error:
`TypeError: thread.addeLabel is not a function`
Thank you so much for all the willingness to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, I thought that the method name of `addeLabel` is required to be modified to `addLabel`. I think that this is the reason of your error message. And, in the case of `addLabel`, the argument is GmailLabel object. When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
thread.addeLabel('a');
```

#### To:

```
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("a");
thread.addLabel(label);
```

#### Refernce:

- [addLabel(label)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#addlabellabel)

Comment: Thank you. I really made mistakes. I thank you for your attention

Comment: @A good person It's no problem. I'm glad your issue was resolved.